# AWS Lambda - node.js - with imagemagick shared lib

Tags: amazon-web-services, node.js, imagemagick

Setup:
- AWS Lambda function
- Using node.js 8.10 runtime
- Using the AWS preinstalled imagemagick lib

The error I'm facing when attempting to transform a *.AI file:
Error: Command failed: convert: unable to load module `/usr/lib64/ImageMagick-6.7.8/modules-Q16/coders/pdf.la': file not found @ error/module.c/OpenModule/1278.
convert: no decode delegate for this image format`/tmp/magick-c0KvODEy' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/544.
convert: no images defined `/tmp/resized.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3046.

Issue:
The AWS Lambda function still works perfectly for *.JPG and *.PNG files. However, for the last 2 weeks (since we've noticed) the above error occurs for *.AI files. I understand *.AI files are treated like PDF due to being Adobe illustrator files, so makes sense why the pdf.la module is required.

Questions:
It seems like the policy.xml and delegates.xml file need changes. However, is this something which can be implemented when using the shared imagemagick lib on AWS?

Has anyone else had similar issues recently and can offer any suggestions?

Could it be that I now need Ghostscript included as a node_module? If so, how to I incorporate imagemagick with ghostscript (I'm guessing the node.js code will require changes for this implementation)?

Thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: This has been asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57067351/imagemagick-not-converting-pdfs-anymore-in-aws-lambda?noredirect=1#comment100713341_57067351